# How to get the time the scenario started in JSystem?

Tags: java, automated-tests, jsystem

I have test that include the time of the start of senario, then i have to know when scenario started in JSystem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have no wait to get the scenario started.
But, you can get the time scenario change last time, it occur when the scenario start:

```
JSystemProperties.getInstance().getPreferencesFile().lastModified()).getMillis()
```

I hope I helped you.